# Weird behaviour when using objects as keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, properties, key

Consider the following snippet:

```
var a = {amount: 300}
var b = {amount: 250}
var c = {[a] : 'bla', [b]: 'blabla'};
console.log(c[a]);
```

It prints:

```
blabla
```

But should it not print:

```
bla
```

What is going on here?

Comment: it's converted to string first (since JS objects may only have string keys), which would be `[object Object]` for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects cannot have other objects as their keys. What's happening is, since the `a` is an invalid key, its `toString` method is called, thus converting `a` into a string. The same thing happens with `[b]`. So, to the interpreter, what you're doing *actually* looks something like this:

```js
var a = {amount: 300}
var b = {amount: 250}
var c = {['object Object'] : 'bla', ['object Object']: 'blabla'};
console.log(c);
```

If you wanted to use objects as keys, you should use a `Map` instead:

```js
var a = {amount: 300}
var b = {amount: 250}
var c = new Map()
  .set(a, 'bla')
  .set(b, 'blabla');
console.log(c.get(a));
```

(Maps can have *anything* as their keys)

Answer (score 4):

When you try to use an object as a key it gets stringified to something like `"[object object]"` and **that** becomes the key. So your `c` object only has one key because it can't have two `[object Object]` properties.

```js
var a = {amount: 300}
var b = {amount: 250}
var c = {[a] : 'bla', [b]: 'blabla'};

// lets look at c's keys
console.log(Object.keys(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `toString()` on your objects. `toString` is a function that exists on all JavaScript Objects and is what gets called when the object is stringified.

Your `toString` implementation will have to generate a unique value. Something like creating a hashcode for your object.

```
var a = {amount: 300, toString: function() {return 'unique 1'}}
var b = {amount: 250, toString: function() {return 'unique 2'}}
var c = {[a] : 'bla', [b]: 'blabla'};
console.log(c[a]);
```

Having a quick look at IE11, it looks like it will never allow an object to be a key.